# How to reconfigure Rails default middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

Rails comes with a range of middleware which is included by default. But what if I want to pass arguments to the middleware? For example, `ActionDispatch::RemoteIp` takes two optional arguments: [`ip_spoofing_check` and `custom_proxies`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/22d9b3e83e03836c5b5d5b05be87ef9467805107/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb#L62). How do I reconfigure the already included `ActionDispatch::RemoteIp` middleware but passing in my own value for `custom_proxies`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `ActionDispatch::RemoteIp` checks for IP spoofing attacks and gets
>   valid client_ip from request headers. Configurable with the
>   `config.action_dispatch.ip_spoofing_check`, and
>   `config.action_dispatch.trusted_proxies` options.
>   - [Rails Guides - Configuring Middleware](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-middleware)

In fact most of the middleware has setters so that you can reconfigure it instead of having to change the initialization arguments.

Comment: Thanks. But what if a middleware did need to be reinitialised? Would it have to be removed and then added back in?

Comment: Yes. But almost all the rails middleware exposes configuration so that you don't have use `config.middleware.swap`.